# The Mssig Pzle - Unhelpful Clues Edition

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**This is part of a series. Solve this puzzle to unlock the next puzzle.**

> The answer is in this sentence.
>
> The answer will be 4 letters, then 2 letters.
>
> Add none together.
>
> Section one, section two.
>
> Two per word.
>
> Title says it all; no articles and first section (Mssig Pzle)
>
> In ache, in envy

Using these unhelpful clues, solve the puzzle of The Mssig Pzle.

Comment: You may want to consider adding a hint, as nobody seems to have made any headway on this puzzle.

Comment: @mkinson Nope.!

Comment: I second @Rubio's request for a hint.

Comment: I'm wondering if "Two per word" indicates that there are two missing letters per word of the answer, so that although the answer will be 4 letters than 2, the full words would contain 6 letters, then 4...

Answer (score 1):

Possible Answer:

> Essence

Explanation:

The answer is in this sentence.

> thi**s sen**t**ence** the letters all exist in "this sentence"

The answer will be 4 letters, then 2 letters.

> Essence is spelled with 4 unique letters, and within the word exists "es" and "en"

Add none together.

> An essence is something that is a concentration.

Section one, section two.

> This part I think means the title and the body of the question given below's "and first section (Mssig Pzle)" statement. U Zin (missing letters of title) in dutch means you sense or you sentence. Although "you sentence" or "sense you" in of itself doesn't mean much In that respect it could indicate an analogy between the puzzles answer if I consider it to be that the title is the "essence" of the entire puzzle itself.

Two per word.

> Again, this one might be a bit of a stretch. Missing and Puzzle each are missing 2 letters from each word. In and Uz. In Romanian Uz in mean in household, where as uz by itself means to (all from Google translate). Could be considered "In house" or I interpret it as "inside". Again, this is a weak explanation and how do I relate it to "essence"? Only that the essence of something is usually a building block (house) within (inside) of something else.

Title says it all; no articles and first section (Mssig Pzle)

> See above 2 very tenuous explanations.

In ache, in envy

> Essences (particularly herbal) are used to sooth all sorts of aches and ailments. Envy I'm lost on honestly..

Probably wrong, but the best I can come up with.

Comment: This is close, but not yet far.